# Storing mutable references owned by someone else

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I want to store structs in HashMap but also reference to same structs inside another struct vector field.

Let's say I have a tree build of two types of structs Item and Relation.

I am storing all the relations in HashMap by their id,
but I also want to fill each item.out_relations vector with mutable references to same Relation structs which are owned by HashMap.

Here is my Item:

```
pub struct Item<'a> {
  pub id: oid::ObjectId,
  pub out_relations: Vec<&'a mut Relation>, // <-- want to fill this
}
```

And when I am iterating over my relations got from DB
I am trying to do smth like this:

```
let from_id = relation.from_id; //to find related item
item_map // my items loaded here already
.entry(from_id)
.and_modify(|item| { 
  (*item)
    .out_relations.push(
      relation_map.try_insert(relation.id, relation).unwrap() // mut ref to relation expected here
    )
  }
);
```

For now compiler warns try_insert is unstable feature and points me to this [bug](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/82766)
But let's imagine I have this mutable ref to relation owned already by HashMap- is it going to work?

Or this will be again some ref lives not long enough error? What are my options then? Or I better will store just relation id in item out_relations vector rather then refs? And when needed I will take my relation from the hashmap?

Comment: Its hard to answer without a complete example, but you'll likely run into problems that persisting a mutable reference to an element in your `relation_map` will lock you out from further mutations of the map. You can only call `.try_insert` *once* because further mutations could invalidate the reference you've already gotten.

Comment: Either have `out_relations: Vec<Rc<RefCell<Relation>>>` and `relation_map: HashMap<Rc<RefCell<Relation>>>` or more simply `out_relations: Vec<RelationId>` and look them up in `relation_map` when you want to mutate them.

Comment: Thank you @Jmb, having vector of id scares me less :)
But do you know what will be faster to use later - Rc/RefCell or accessing HashMap by id?

Comment: @YuriGor There's no way to know which will be faster without benchmarking with real data. So I'd advise to go with whichever solution you feel more comfortable with, and only try to optimize once you have a working solution (and only if measurements show that this part of the code represents a real performance bottleneck).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called shared mutability, and it is forbidden by the borrow checker.
Fortunately Rust offers safe tools to achieve this.
In your case you need to use Rc<RefCell>, so your code would be:

```
pub struct Item {
  pub id: oid::ObjectId,
  pub out_relations: Vec<Rc<RefCell<Relation>>>,
}
```

And when I am iterating over my relations got from DB I am trying to do smth like this:

```
let relation = Rc::new(RefCell::new(relation));

let from_id = relation.borrow().from_id; // assuming id is a Copy type
item_map // my items loaded here already
.entry(from_id)
.and_modify(|item| { 
  (*item)
    .out_relations.push(
      relation_map.try_insert(relation.id, relation.clone()).unwrap() // mut ref to relation expected here
    )
  }
);
```

If you want to mutate relation later, you can use `.borrow_mut()`

```
relation.borrow_mut().from_id = new_id;
```

Comment: Thank you, looks like I need to learn this Rc<RefCell> stuff, but do you know what will be faster to use later - Rc/RefCell or accessing HashMap by id? If let's say I will have 
out_relations: Vec<oid::ObjectId> and when I need my relation - I will get it from HasMap with all my relations? Does it repend on HashMap size?

Comment: Depends on the size of your data. The fastest thing would be a contingious array, so the ids need to be the array index, in order for the array to not grow too big, you can use generational arrays. So the id will be composed by 2 numbers, when to refer to the array, the other is to the index in array, it is like a 2d array, where you drop old arrays and you create new ones. Rc<RefCell> will be faster than a HashMap, it is an integer increment vs Hash function.

Comment: Thank you! What can I read more about generational arrays? Why it should be better then usual Vec? I have limited list of items which I load from DB one time, is it going to be some overhead due to bigger capacity of vec compared to actual data size? 
Or you mean accessing Vec by bigger index closer to the end of the list takes more time? In my case I dont expect more then 1K records but gonna access them millions of times.

Comment: If it is a contigious list of integers (1,2,3,4,5) then use a regular array (no matter what the size of your data is), if it is not(1,2,3, 500000,5000001) then you need to use generational arrays since with regular arrays you will have a lot of empty values. I know `specs` uses generational arrays, and most of ECS frameworks do. you can probably find some crate for that.

Comment: Ok, got it, thanks. Well i will just push all my record to the array one by one and update each record to have index in this array as internal id so it will be normal continues array. Inside item i will store this array indexes instead of original id, that should work i guess, and work fast.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Oussama Gammoudi's diagnosis, but I'd like to offer alternative solutions.

The issue with reference counting is that it kills performance.

In your vector, can you store the key to the hash map instead?  Then, when you need to get the value from the vector, get the key from the vector and fetch the value from the hash map?

Another strategy is to keep a vector of the values, and then store indices into the vector in your hash map and other vector.  This Rust Keynote speaker describes the strategy well: https://youtu.be/aKLntZcp27M?t=1787

Comment: Thank you!
Indexes was my first idea, but I didn't like to have main vector + hashmap + vectors in items, so 3 things to keep in mind.
And I thought access items via HashTable by key -> in vector by index will be slower. Maybe I will try to get rid of HashMap and always rely on indexes by storing index in relation as internal id

That's really interesting about slow performance of Rc, is there something to read more?

I am also fine to have this data read-only, or changing in rare cases, so maybe I will just clone these relations to items vectors.  And if needed - mutate all the clones.